# Problema de salida por pantalla con PHP y JSON

Tags: php, html, json, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código:

```
<html>
 <body>

<?php

$url_principal = ""; //aquí va la url que corresponda

if (isset($_GET["action"]) && isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["action"] == "get_datos_autor"){

    $app_info = file_get_contents($url_principal."api.php?action=get_datos_autor&id=".$_GET["id"]);
    
    $app_info = json_decode($app_info, true);
?>
    <div>
    <p>
        <td><b>Nombre: </b></td><td> <?php echo $app_info["datos"]["nombre"] ?></td>
    </p>
    <p>
        <td><b>Apellidos: </b></td><td> <?php echo $app_info["datos"]["apellidos"] ?></td>
    </p>
    <p>
        <td><b>Nacionalidad: </b></td><td> <?php echo $app_info["datos"]["nacionalidad"] ?></td>
    </p>
    <ul>
    
    <?php foreach($app_info["libros"] as $libro): ?>
        <li>
            <a href=<?php echo $url_principal."/cliente.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=".$libro["id"]; ?>>
            <?php echo $libro["titulo"]; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>   
    <br />
    <!-- Enlace para volver a la lista de autores -->
    <a href=<?php echo $url_principal."cliente.php?action=get_lista_autores"; ?>  alt="Lista de autores">Volver a la lista de autores</a>
    </div>
<?php
}
else if(isset($_GET["action"]) && isset($_GET["id"]) && $_GET["action"] == "get_datos_libro"){

    $app_info = file_get_contents($url_principal."/api.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=".$_GET["id"]);
    $app_info = json_decode($app_info, true);

?>
<div>
    <p><td><b>Título: </b></td> <td><?php echo $app_info["titulo"] ?></td></p>
    <p><td><b>Fecha de publicación: </b></td> <td><?php echo $app_info["f_publicacion"] ?></td></p>
    <p><td><b>Autor del libro: </b></td> 
        <td>
            <a href=<?php echo $url_principal."/cliente.php?action=get_datos_autor&id=".$app_info["id_autor"] ?> >
                <?php echo $app_info["nombre"]." ".$app_info["apellidos"] ?>
            </a>
        </td>
    </p>
    <a href=<?php $url_principal."/cliente.php?action=get_lista_ibros" ?> alt="Lista de libros" ></a>
</div>    
<?php 

}else {
    
    $lista_autores = file_get_contents($url_principal."/api.php?action=get_lista_autores");

    $lista_libros = file_get_contents($url_principal."/api.php?action=get_lista_libros");

    $lista_autores = json_decode($lista_autores, true);
    $lista_libros = json_decode($lista_libros, true);
?>
    <h3>Lista de autores</h3>
    <ul>
    
    <?php foreach($lista_autores as $autores): ?>
        <li>
            <!-- Enlazamos cada nombre de autor con su informacion (primer if) -->
            <a href="<?php echo $url_principal."cliente.php?action=get_datos_autor&id=" . $autores["id"]  ?>">
            <?php echo $autores["nombre"] . " " . $autores["apellidos"] ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>Lista de libros</h3>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach($lista_libros as $libro): ?>
        <li>
            <a href=<?php echo $url_principal."/cliente.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=".$libro["id"] ?> >
            <?php echo $libro["titulo"]?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </ul>
  <?php } ?>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

El problema es que no se vuelcan los datos por pantalla y desconozco el porqué. Por pantalla se muestra únicamente un problema con los últimos foreach, porque no detecta que la variable es un array derivado de JSON. Sin embargo, si soluciono ese problema (con un if(is_array)), el error desaparece pero sigue sin salir por pantalla los datos solicitados

El esquema de directorios es el siguiente (cliente.php es el código arriba indicado y además el index):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la carpeta vendor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si es necesario aportar más imágenes o más fragmentos de código, por favor, indicádmelo.

Gracias por adelantado.

Nota: los archivos Mate, cliente_soap_mate y servidor_soap_mate no están relacionados con este código

Edición: añado el código de la API

```
<?php

require "gestionLibros.php";

function get_lista_autores(){

   $gestionLibros = new gestionLibros();
   $conexion = $gestionLibros->conexion("localhost", "root","","libros");
   $lista_autores = $gestionLibros->consultarAutores($conexion);
    
    return $lista_autores;
}

function get_datos_autor($id){

    $gestionLibros = new gestionLibros();
    $conexion = $gestionLibros->conexion("localhost", "root","","libros");
    $autor = $gestionLibros->consultarAutores($conexion, $id);
    $libros_autor = $gestionLibros->consultarLibros($conexion, $id);
    
    return array(
      "datos" => $autor,
      "libros" => $libros_autor 
    );
}

function get_lista_libros(){
  $gestionLibros = new gestionLibros();
  $conexion = $gestionLibros->conexion("localhost","root","","libros");
  $respuestaLibros = $gestionLibros->consultarLibros($conexion);
  $libros = array();

  foreach($respuestaLibros as $libro){
    $nuevoLibro = array(
      "id" => $libro["id"],
      "titulo" => $libro["titulo"]
    );

    array_push($libros, $nuevoLibro);
  }

  return $libros;

}

function get_datos_libro($id){
  $gestionLibros = new gestionLibros();
  $conexion = $gestionLibros->conexion("localhost","root","","libros");
  $libro = $gestionLibros->consultarDatosLibro($conexion, $id);
  $autor = $gestionLibros->consultarAutores($conexion, $libro["id_autor"]);

  return[
    "titulo" => $libro["titulo"],
    "f_publicacion" => $libro["f_publicacion"],
    "nombre" => $autor["nombre"],
    "apellidos" => $autor["apellidos"],
    "id_autor" => $autor["id"]
  ];

}


$posibles_URL = array("get_lista_autores", "get_datos_autor", "get_lista_libros","get_datos_libro");

$valor = "Ha ocurrido un error";

if (isset($_GET["action"]) && in_array($_GET["action"], $posibles_URL))
{
  switch ($_GET["action"])
    {
      case "get_lista_autores":
        $valor = get_lista_autores();
        break;
      case "get_datos_autor":
        if (isset($_GET["id"]))
            $valor = get_datos_autor($_GET["id"]);
        else
            $valor = "Argumento no encontrado";
        break;
      case "get_lista_libros":
        $valor = get_lista_libros();
        break;  
      case "get_datos_libro":
        if(isset($_GET["id"]))
          $valor = get_datos_libro($_GET["id"]);
        else 
          $valor = "Argumento no encontrado";
        break;  
    }
}

exit(json_encode($valor));
?>
```

Comment: Estaría bien ver el código (o lo que se pueda) del archivo api.php para ver qué respuesta (y qué tipo de estructura tiene) ofrece la consulta.
Y también que hagas un `var_dump` o `print_r` de `$app_info` en cuanto la recibes y en cuanto haces el json_decode.
Ya de paso, yo utilizaría dos variables en lugar de una. Por ejemplo, `$app_info`y otra `$arr_app_info`

Comment: Buenas @VFG . He añadido el código de api.php. El acceso a la base de datos tiene esos datos de conexión porque es una prueba

Comment: Bien... aparentemente en ese script todo está bien (entendiendo que las llamadas a los métodos de gestionLibros están bien).
Haz un die y/o un `echo print_r($app_info);` justo después de la llamada `json_decode` para ver qué dato te ha devuelto y si está bien decodificado.

Comment: He colocado lo que me has comentado después de la línea $app_info = json_decode($app_info, true); y por pantalla sale el listado de autores y libros. Eso sí, no funcionan los enlaces que aparecen por pantalla :/

Comment: La cosa es que he comentado la línea que me has dicho que pusiera (es decir, dejando el código tal y como estaba) y ahora el listado sigue apareciendo :S

Comment: Haz un `var_dump($app_info);` y agrega el resultado a la pregunta para que revisemos. Puede que la estructura del array sea diferente, o que no contenga todos los datos que crees. Es un caso típico de defecto en la depuración.

Comment: He hecho un var_dump($app_info) en la misma línea en la que he puesto antes el echo y por pantalla no sale nada, al margen de la lista

Comment: Si alguno prefiere pasar esto a un chat, yo encantado. Me interesa solucionar esto pronto y si es posible por el chat pasar más información, pues me viene mejor

Comment: ¿Quieres decir que lo pusiste en uno de los bloques de tus condicionales? Si no sale nada, significa que no estaría entrando en ese bloque. Como ya dije, es un problema típico de depuración. Sigue la traza al código, verifica por donde entra o no entra, depura variables y encontrarás el problema. Si no se ve el `var_dump` empieza por verificar si esa condición se cumple, revisando las variables que evalúas ahí.

Comment: Así, una fuerte candidata a ser depurada es tu super global. Pon un `var_dump($_GET);` al principio del código y revisa lo que hay en ella. Te aconsejo que aprendas a depurar, te ahorrarás muuuuuchas horas, días y muchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Las ligas va entrecomilladas: `href=" ... "`, seguramente no ves nada por que resulta un html malformado.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría que evites la mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML. Produce un código confuso y difícil de analizar/depurar.

Pensar el código lo más posible dentro de un contexto PHP permite aplicar una lógica más clara, y añadir controles fundamentales.

En el ejemplo, guardaremos el id y el action en una variable verificando con fusión de full (si no tienes PHP 7 o superior debes cambiarlo por un ternario).

Luego organizaremos mejor la lógica: verificaremos primero que `$id` y `$action` tienen valores, y en lo adelante desplegaremos la lógica para cada action.

Verificaremos también que el json tiene datos, imprimiendo en caso contrario un mensaje de error. Esto lo puedes cambiar por otra cosa. El asunto es que tu código deja bloques en blanco, haciendo que sea mudo si no hay datos.

Al escribir un código más claro te das cuenta de errores como el que menciona @Sal en su comentario (debes usar `"` para escribir el `href`). Y hay más errores, por ejemplo, en las URL, a veces no pones esto `/`, lo cual crearía una URL errónea. Por cierto, he cambiado tu variable por una más breve que se llama `$url`. Usar variables kilométricas producirá líneas kilométricas que afectan a la legibilidad del código. No significa que haya que sacrificar el sentido del código, el nombre de la variable debe indicar de qué se trata. En este caso, al ver `$url` ya sabemos qué es (conviene una convención de nombre en inglés, que permite variables más cortas, por ejemplo `$homeURL`).

Dicho esto, mi propuesta es esta, espero no haber errado en nada. Así debería funcionar y si no funciona, verás un mensaje de error.

```
<html>
 <body>
<?php

#Evita variables muy largas
$url = ""; //aquí va la url que corresponda
$action=$_GET["action"] ?? null;
$id=$_GET["id"] ?? null;

if($action && $id) {

    if($action == "get_datos_autor") {
        $content = file_get_contents("$url/api.php?action=get_datos_autor&id=$id");
        $app_info = json_decode($content, true);
        if($app_info) { 
            $html=sprintf("<div>
                <p>
                    <td><b>Nombre: </b></td><td>%s</td>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <td><b>Apellidos: </b></td><td>%s</td>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <td><b>Nacionalidad: </b></td><td>%s</td>
                </p>
                <ul>",
                $app_info["datos"]["nombre"],
                $app_info["datos"]["apellidos"], 
                $app_info["datos"]["nacionalidad"]);
            foreach($app_info["libros"] as $libro) {
                $html.=
                    "<li>
                        <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=$libro[id]\">$libro[titulo]</a>
                    </li>";
            }
            $html.="</ul><br />
            <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_lista_autores\" alt=\"Lista de autores\">Volver a la lista de autores</a>
            </div>";        
        } else { 
            $html="<p>json autor erróneo o vacío</p>";
        }
    } else if($action == "get_datos_libro") {
        $content = file_get_contents("$url/api.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=$id");
        $app_info = json_decode($content, true);
        if ($app_info) {
            $html="<div>
            <p><td><b>Título: </b></td> <td>%s</td></p>
            <p><td><b>Fecha de publicación: </b></td> <td>%s</td></p>
            <p><td><b>Autor del libro: </b></td> 
                <td>
                    <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_datos_autor&id=$app_info[id_autor]\">
                        $app_info[nombre] $app_info[apellidos]
                    </a>
                </td>
            </p>
            <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_lista_libros\" alt=\"Lista de libros\">FALTA TEXTO AQUÍ</a>
        </div>";        
        } else {
            $html="<p>json datos libro erróneo o vacío</p>";    
        }
    } else {
        $dataAutores = file_get_contents("$url/api.php?action=get_lista_autores");
        $dataLibros = file_get_contents($url."/api.php?action=get_lista_libros");
        $html="";   
        $autores = json_decode($dataAutores, true);
        $libros = json_decode($dataLibros, true);
        
        if($autores) {
            $html.="<h3>Lista de autores</h3>";
            $html.="<ul>";  
            foreach($autores as $autor) {
                $html.="<li>
                <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_datos_autor&id="$autores[id]\">
                $autores[nombre] $autores[apellidos]</a>
                </li>";
            }
            $html.="</ul>";                 
        } else {
            $html.="<p>Lista autores sin datos</p>";
        }
        
        if ($libros) {
            $html.="<h3>Lista de libros</h3>";
            $html.="<ul>";
        foreach($libros as $libro) {
            $html.="<li>
                <a href=\"$url/cliente.php?action=get_datos_libro&id=$libro[id]\">$libro[titulo]</a>
                </li>";
            }
            $html.="</ul>";     
        } else {
            $html.="<p>Lista libros sin datos</p>"; 
        }
    }

} else {
    $html="<p>Datos del GET vacíos</p>";
}
echo $html;
?>
 </body>
</html>
```